# Why is $(GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3),\cdot)$ a group?

Tags: matrices, group-theory, finite-groups

I am doing an exercise  where I have to use that $(GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3),\cdot)$ is group. I just have a hard time accepting that this a group. $GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)$ is described as "the set of invertible $2 \times2 $ matrices with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$". The $\cdot$ is simply the ordinary matrix multiplication operator. I don't understand how the group axiom that every element in $(GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3),\cdot)$ has an inverse in $(GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3),\cdot)$ is satisfied. For example the matrix
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 1 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} \in GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)$$ has inverse
$$\begin{bmatrix} 2/3 & -1/3 \\ -1/3 & 2/3 \end{bmatrix}.$$
Now this matrix should be in $(GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)$?

Why?

I guess since we are working with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, we should take modulo 3 on all the coefficients, but the problem here is that that's not possible since $gcd(3,3)=3 \neq 1$.

I suspect that I have some fundamental misunderstanding; can anyone explain what I am missing here?

Thanks

Comment: No, $3=0$ in this field. But you cannot divide by zero. Hence the matrix is not in $GL(2,3)$. It's determinant is zero.

Comment: $\begin{bmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{bmatrix}$ is singular since its determinant is $0$. Hence it isn't part of $\operatorname{GL}(2,\mathbb{Z}_3)$ and doesn't need an inverse.

Comment: Perhaps an easy way to see this matrix is not invertible is to note that in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, $2=-1$ and $1=-2$. So the first row can be rewritten as $(-1,1)$ and the second row as $(1,-1)$. Clearly, the first row is a scalar multiple of the second, so the matrix is not full rank.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]\notin GL(2,\Bbb Z_3)$, since $\det\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&1\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]=0$ (in $\Bbb Z_3$).

But, for instance, $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&2\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]\in GL(2,\Bbb Z_3)$, and its inverse is $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$, since (doing the computations in $\Bbb Z_3$),$$\begin{bmatrix}2&2\\1&2\end{bmatrix}.\begin{bmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1&0\\0&1\end{bmatrix}.$$

And the way I got $\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&2\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]^{-1}=\left[\begin{smallmatrix}1&2\\1&1\end{smallmatrix}\right]$ was this: I computed $\det\left[\begin{smallmatrix}2&2\\1&2\end{smallmatrix}\right]=2$, I computed its inverse, which is again $2$ ($2\times2=1$ in $\Bbb Z_3$), and then I used the formula$$\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}=\left(\det\left(\begin{bmatrix}a&b\\c&d\end{bmatrix}\right)\right)^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}d&-b\\-c&a\end{bmatrix}.$$

Comment: Hmm. So when I am working in $\mathbb{Z}_3$, every operation I can think of doing, e.g. taking the determinant, has to be under modulo 3?

Comment: Yes, that is correct!

Answer (score 2):

By definition, $GL_2(K)$ is the group of *invertible* $2\times 2$ matrices over $K=\Bbb F_3$. However, your matrix has determinant $3=0$, so is *not* invertible.

Regarding your title question "Why is $(GL(2,\mathbb{Z}_3),\cdot)$ a group?":

In general, $GL_n(K)$ is a group for *every* field $K$. For the proof we only need that $\det(AB)=\det(A)\det(B)$ to see that with $A,B$ also $AB$ and $A^{-1}$ is again in $GL_n(K)$.